# Stop Android Publication

Tags: android, google-play

I have finished my game and I want to release it on the Google Play Store. I had the whole store listing ready for publishing but I was going to save the release date to a later time. I accidentally clicked the Publish App button and I can't figure out how to stop the Play Store from releasing my game. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unpublish button in the google play dev console.